# HP USB Graphics Adapter Drivers for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers

Has anyone seen Windows 7 drivers yet for the HP USB Graphics Adapter?

Comment: I should add note that I am also running 64bit as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ditto to oneguynick's answer. I don't know the HP one, but the EVGA+ adapter I have uses the DisplayLink driver. From what I've seen online, most USB display adapters are powered by DisplayLink.

Comment: Took me awhile to check back, but that WORKED!  Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

[DisplayLink Windows 7 Drivers](http://www.displaylink.com/support/windows7.html)

Not sure what chipset is in the USB adapter you have, but this would be my first start.